# Linq to 3 tables with no foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I have 3 tables without foreign keys (it's a legacy db, so I can't change that).
The model will be something like this (sql code):

```
Select 
    PROD.ProductoId, 
    PROD.Descripcion,
    STK.StockActual,
    DEPO.DepositoId,
    DEPO.Descripcion
From 
     Productos  PROD, 
     Stock      STOK, 
     Depositos  DEPO
where 
    PROD.ProductoId = STOK.ProductoId
    and  DEPO.DepositoId = STOK.DepositoId
```

How can I do to get the same results with Linq on C#?

Comment: Off-topic advice: Specify table joins explicitly, i.e. using `JOIN` syntax: `… FROM Productos PROD JOIN Stock STOK ON PROD.ProductoId = STOK.ProductoId JOIN Depositos DEPO ON DEPO.DepositoId = STOK.DepositoId`. See [this Programmers SE Q & A](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/78225/using-join-keyword-or-not) for reasons why to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = from prod in _context.Productos
             join stok in _context.Stocks on prod.ProductoId equals stok.ProductoId
             join depo in _context.Depositos on stok.DepositoId equals depo.DepositoId
             select new
             {
                 ProductoId = prod.ProductoId,
                 ProductoDescripcion = prod.Descripcion,
                 StockActual = stok.StockActual,
                 DepositoId = depo.DepositoId,
                 DepositoDescripcion = depo.Descripcion
             };
```

Comment: I'll try it and then I'll post the result! Thank you!!

Comment: Sure, I'm not sure if it's correct. I just started using linq myself.

Comment: I think after the first join you should select PROD.ProductoId, PROD.Descripcion, STK.StockActual, STOK.DepositoId into new table and join your new table with deposit table

Comment: @NamBình, add the `select` part in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you create a View in Sql and then update your model, that way you can query from the View class.

Comment: Tks but I can't create nothing in the db because is from a third part system.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var Query = from data in _db.Productos  
join stock in _db.Stock on data.ProductId equals stock.ProductoId
join Depositos in _db.Depositos on data.DepositoId equals Depositos.DepositoId
select new { ProductoId,Descripcion, StockActual,DepositoId,Descripcion};
```